# What's the complexity to check whether a matrix is Diagonalizable?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with rational entries. What's the complexity to check $A$ is diagonalizable?

I suspect that this can be done in P, but I do not know any reference. However, a more interesting question is, is there any better complexity class to capture this problem?

Any guidance/comment is welcome! Thanks.

Comment: By computing and factoring the characteristic polynomial, you can check in polynomial time whether the matrix is diagonalizable. I do not know better bounds for this problem.

Comment: @Bruno are you assuming that a matrix is diagonalizable iff it has distinct eigenvalues? This it not true, it is a sufficent but not necessary condition. An identity matrix is a counterexample.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: I was assuming the equivalent fact that a matrix is diagonalizable iff its characteristic polynomial is a product of distinct linear factors. Of course, the equivalence does not hold for the characteristic polynomial but the minimal polynomial...

Comment: To compensate my mistake, here is a reference for a polynomial time algorithm to compute the minimal polynomial, from which you easily obtain (or extract) an algorithm for checking diagonalizability: [On the computation of minimal polynomials, cyclic vectors, and frobenius forms](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(97)80005-5), by Daniel Augot and Paul Camion.

Comment: You can compute the Jordan canonical form of a rational matrix in polynomial time: http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0129054194000165

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this in uniform NC, see:

G. Villard. Fast parallel algorithms for matrix reduction to canonical forms. AAECC 8:511-537, 1997. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002000050089